Procedural fractal Perlin flow noise for mobile
I'm trying to use the Fractal Perlin flow noise from Chaos Software (shared under the MIT licence)
int fastFloor(float x) {
    return (x < 0) ? int(x) - 1 : int(x);
}
 
float fade(float t) {
    return t * t * t * (t * (t * 6.0 - 15.0) + 10.0);
}
 
float lerp(float t, float a, float b) {
    return a + t * (b - a);
}
 
/// 3D Perlin flow noise implementation.
/// Returned values are in the [0, 1] range.
float perlinFlowNoise3D(point position, float flow) {
    int perm[512] = {
        151,160,137,91,90,15,
        131,13,201,95,96,53,194,233,7,225,140,36,103,30,69,142,8,99,37,240,21,10,23,
        190, 6,148,247,120,234,75,0,26,197,62,94,252,219,203,117,35,11,32,57,177,33,
        88,237,149,56,87,174,20,125,136,171,168, 68,175,74,165,71,134,139,48,27,166,
        77,146,158,231,83,111,229,122,60,211,133,230,220,105,92,41,55,46,245,40,244,
        102,143,54, 65,25,63,161, 1,216,80,73,209,76,132,187,208, 89,18,169,200,196,
        135,130,116,188,159,86,164,100,109,198,173,186, 3,64,52,217,226,250,124,123,
        5,202,38,147,118,126,255,82,85,212,207,206,59,227,47,16,58,17,182,189,28,42,
        223,183,170,213,119,248,152, 2,44,154,163, 70,221,153,101,155,167, 43,172,9,
        129,22,39,253, 19,98,108,110,79,113,224,232,178,185, 112,104,218,246,97,228,
        251,34,242,193,238,210,144,12,191,179,162,241, 81,51,145,235,249,14,239,107,
        49,192,214, 31,181,199,106,157,184, 84,204,176,115,121,50,45,127, 4,150,254,
        138,236,205,93,222,114,67,29,24,72,243,141,128,195,78,66,215,61,156,180,
        151,160,137,91,90,15,
        131,13,201,95,96,53,194,233,7,225,140,36,103,30,69,142,8,99,37,240,21,10,23,
        190, 6,148,247,120,234,75,0,26,197,62,94,252,219,203,117,35,11,32,57,177,33,
        88,237,149,56,87,174,20,125,136,171,168, 68,175,74,165,71,134,139,48,27,166,
        77,146,158,231,83,111,229,122,60,211,133,230,220,105,92,41,55,46,245,40,244,
        102,143,54, 65,25,63,161, 1,216,80,73,209,76,132,187,208, 89,18,169,200,196,
        135,130,116,188,159,86,164,100,109,198,173,186, 3,64,52,217,226,250,124,123,
        5,202,38,147,118,126,255,82,85,212,207,206,59,227,47,16,58,17,182,189,28,42,
        223,183,170,213,119,248,152, 2,44,154,163, 70,221,153,101,155,167, 43,172,9,
        129,22,39,253, 19,98,108,110,79,113,224,232,178,185, 112,104,218,246,97,228,
        251,34,242,193,238,210,144,12,191,179,162,241, 81,51,145,235,249,14,239,107,
        49,192,214, 31,181,199,106,157,184, 84,204,176,115,121,50,45,127, 4,150,254,
        138,236,205,93,222,114,67,29,24,72,243,141,128,195,78,66,215,61,156,180
    };
     
    // Gradient component that leads to a vector of length sqrt(2).
    // float a = sqrt(2)/sqrt(3);
    float a = 0.81649658;
     
    vector gradientUBase[16] = {
        vector( 1.0,  0.0,  1.0), vector( 0.0,  1.0,  1.0),
        vector(-1.0,  0.0,  1.0), vector( 0.0, -1.0,  1.0),
        vector( 1.0,  0.0, -1.0), vector( 0.0,  1.0, -1.0),
        vector(-1.0,  0.0, -1.0), vector( 0.0, -1.0, -1.0),
        vector( a,  a,  a), vector(-a,  a, -a),
        vector(-a, -a,  a), vector( a, -a, -a),
        vector(-a,  a,  a), vector( a, -a,  a),
        vector( a, -a, -a), vector(-a,  a, -a)
    };
 
    vector gradientVBase[16] = {
        vector(-a,  a,  a), vector(-a, -a,  a),
        vector( a, -a,  a), vector( a,  a,  a),
        vector(-a, -a, -a), vector( a, -a, -a),
        vector( a,  a, -a), vector(-a,  a, -a),
        vector( 1.0, -1.0,  0.0), vector( 1.0,  1.0,  0.0),
        vector(-1.0,  1.0,  0.0), vector(-1.0, -1.0,  0.0),
        vector( 1.0,  0.0,  1.0), vector(-1.0,  0.0,  1.0),
        vector( 0.0,  1.0, -1.0), vector( 0.0, -1.0, -1.0)
    };
     
    // Helper function to compute the rotated gradient.
    vector getGradient(int index, float sinTheta, float cosTheta) {
        int safeIndex = index % 16;
        vector gradientU = gradientUBase[safeIndex];
        vector gradientV = gradientVBase[safeIndex];
        return cosTheta * gradientU + sinTheta * gradientV;
    }
     
    float gradientDot(int index, float sinTheta, float cosTheta, float x, float y, float z) {
        vector gradient = getGradient(index, sinTheta, cosTheta);
        vector value = vector(x, y, z);
        return dot(gradient, value);
    }
 
    float x = position[0];
    float y = position[1];
    float z = position[2];
     
    int ix = fastFloor(x);
    int iy = fastFloor(y);
    int iz = fastFloor(z);
     
    float fx = x - float(ix);
    float fy = y - float(iy);
    float fz = z - float(iz);
     
    ix = ix & 255;
    iy = iy & 255;
    iz = iz & 255;
     
    float i = fade(fx);
    float j = fade(fy);
    float k = fade(fz);
     
    int A = perm[ix    ] + iy, AA = perm[A] + iz, AB = perm[A + 1] + iz;
    int B = perm[ix + 1] + iy, BA = perm[B] + iz, BB = perm[B + 1] + iz;
     
    // Sine and cosine for the gradient rotation angle
    float sinTheta = 0.0;
    float cosTheta = 0.0;
    sincos(M_2PI * flow, sinTheta, cosTheta);
 
    float noiseValue =
        lerp(k, lerp(j, lerp(i, gradientDot(perm[AA    ], sinTheta, cosTheta, fx      , fy      , fz      ),
                                gradientDot(perm[BA    ], sinTheta, cosTheta, fx - 1.0, fy      , fz      )),
                        lerp(i, gradientDot(perm[AB    ], sinTheta, cosTheta, fx      , fy - 1.0, fz      ),
                                gradientDot(perm[BB    ], sinTheta, cosTheta, fx - 1.0, fy - 1.0, fz      ))),
                lerp(j, lerp(i, gradientDot(perm[AA + 1], sinTheta, cosTheta, fx      , fy      , fz - 1.0),
                                gradientDot(perm[BA + 1], sinTheta, cosTheta, fx - 1.0, fy      , fz - 1.0)),
                        lerp(i, gradientDot(perm[AB + 1], sinTheta, cosTheta, fx      , fy - 1.0, fz - 1.0),
                                gradientDot(perm[BB + 1], sinTheta, cosTheta, fx - 1.0, fy - 1.0, fz - 1.0))));
     
    // Scale to the [0, 1] range.
    return 0.5 * noiseValue + 0.5;
}
 
vector perlinFlowNoise3DGradient(vector position, float flow, float delta) {
    vector result = vector(
        perlinFlowNoise3D(position + vector(delta, 0.0, 0.0), flow) -
        perlinFlowNoise3D(position - vector(delta, 0.0, 0.0), flow),
        perlinFlowNoise3D(position + vector(0.0, delta, 0.0), flow) -
        perlinFlowNoise3D(position - vector(0.0, delta, 0.0), flow),
        perlinFlowNoise3D(position + vector(0.0, 0.0, delta), flow) -
        perlinFlowNoise3D(position - vector(0.0, 0.0, delta), flow)
    );
 
    result /= (2.0 * delta);
 
    return result;
}
 
/// 3D Fractal Perlin flow noise implementation.
/// Returned values are in the [-1, 1] range.
float fractalPerlinFlowNoise3D(
    point position,
    float flow,
    float lacunarity,
    float flowRate,
    float gain,
    float advect,
    int octaveCount
) {
    float noiseValue = 0.0;
 
    float flowValue = flow;
     
    float amplitude = 1.0;
    float advectionAmount = advect;
 
    for (int octave = 0; octave < octaveCount; ++octave) {
        float noiseOctave = amplitude * (perlinFlowNoise3D(position, flowValue) - 0.5);
        noiseValue += noiseOctave;
 
        if (advectionAmount != 0.0) {
            position -= advectionAmount * noiseOctave * perlinFlowNoise3DGradient(position, flow, 0.01);
        }
 
        position *= lacunarity;
        flowValue *= flowRate;
        amplitude *= gain;
        advectionAmount *= advect;
    }
     
    return noiseValue;
}
 
shader FractalPerlinFlowNoise
    [[ string description = "Fractal Perlin flow noise" ]]
(
    float start_frequency = 1.0
        [[ string description = "Initial sampling position multiplier that affects the overall granularity." ]],
    vector start_offset = vector(0.0)
        [[ string description = "Offsets the initial sampling position effectively shifting the pattern in the specified direction." ]],
         
    float flow = 1.0
        [[ string description = "The coordinate of a special noise dimension with a period of 1 that naturally evolves the noise to animate it instead of sliding a 3D slice throught the noise space." ]],
     
    float lacunarity = 2.0
        [[ string description = "Position (frequency) multiplier per iteration." ]],
    float flow_rate = 1.0
        [[ string description = "Flow coordinate multiplier per iteration." ]],
    float gain = 0.5
        [[ string description = "Amplitude multiplier per iteration." ]],
    float advect = 0.5
        [[ string description = "Both initial advection amount and advection multiplier per iteration." ]],
    int octaves = 8
        [[ string description = "Number of fractal iterations." ]],
 
    float attenuation = 1.0
        [[ string description = "The power of the falloff applied to the final result." ]],
     
    output color result = 0.0
) {
    point objectPosition = transform("object", P);
    point startPosition = start_frequency * objectPosition - start_offset;
 
    float noiseValue = fractalPerlinFlowNoise3D(startPosition, flow, lacunarity, flow_rate, gain, advect, octaves);
     
    noiseValue = 0.5 * noiseValue + 0.5;
    noiseValue = pow(noiseValue, attenuation);
     
    result = color(noiseValue);
}

But this code is hard to run on a mobile platform using OpenGL ES.
How can I make it faster / more lightweight for low-spec devices?

Have you identified what aspect of this is "hard to run" or a performance bottleneck for your target hardware?

Reading further down in the linked source, I noticed this: "Simplex flow noise uses true analytic derivatives that give a significant performance edge over the Perlin flow noise." That strongly suggests to me that there are some performance issues with Perlin flow noise and implementing it on mobile is likely to make the issues even more noticeable. Why not use the more performant Simplex version?

thanks so much! noticed that and still trying
